# php session variable not saving

Tags: c#, php, facebook, session

I am quite new to php and am trying to send data from c# to a php script which then posts to facebook.

The trouble is, after I receive the data I can't store it in the session array.

Here's what I've got:

```
session_start();

if($_POST['Facebook'])
{
    echo 'DataReceived';
    $HighScore = $_POST['Facebook'];
    $_SESSION[1] = $HighScore;
}

$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
```

Further down, after checking if the user is not logged into facebook I have:

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params = array('scope' => "publish_stream",));
echo $login_url;
```

I then use this url in c# to open the user's browser where they can login to facebook through my facebook app.

Now, as far as I can tell, the `$login_url` will allow the the user to log into facebook then go back to this php page, this is where I lose the data that I sent from c#.

Also, after using `var_dump($_SESSION)` to check what was there and it contained `$_SESSION['foo']`, some facebook session variables, but not the highscore.

Comment: try changing $_SESSION[1] to $_SESSION['highscore'] or something.

Comment: @techie_28 thanks but i had that previously and changed it to 1 hoping it would work somehow

Comment: Please do a session var dump before getting the $login_url and see if the index and value is there or not. Which means right after setting them in a session after $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';

Comment: It seems odd to me why are you getting the loginUrl from PHP in C# then using it for login and then redirecting back to PHP?Shouldn't it be redirected back to your C#?And facebook also provides SDK for C# as well.

Comment: Just did that and it contained both session variables i added but not the facebook ones, could it be that when my php page is accessed after logging into facebook, the session_start() starts a new session? or possibly the facebook api is doing something undesireable?

Comment: Well I guess when you call the PHP script from your C# then you are setting the session and then accessing the login url in C# and then again after using it you are redirecting it back to your PHP page.SO the initial session which you are talking of was set between your C# and PHP script in the first go.I thought there must be a problem with that but then you sadid you were able to access $_SESSION['foo'] on that PHP script.It seems altogether grim to me

Comment: I thought using the php sdk might make my c# application more platform independent (it's going to be on mobile and desktop), looks like i've just created headaches though.

Comment: thanks for your help techie, gonna take a look at the c# sdk

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are getting the `$_POST['Facebook']` Facebook parameter in `$_POST` because I see no problem in the code.

Comment: Just double checked, and i am getting DataReceived. Im still a php novice, so im sorry if this is incorrect but that should mean the if statement is working?